# PHP Edit Value of stdClass Object

Tags: php

I have an array called `$list` that returns multiple values, I'm looping through this and displaying these values. I need to edit one of the original values.

Here's the result of;

```
print("<pre>".print_r($list,true)."</pre>");

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Home
            [link] => /example/
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Items
            [link] => /example/locations/items   <-- I want to edit this value
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Paris
            [link] => /example/locations/paris
        )

)
```

The code below;

```
foreach ($list as $key => $item) {
    echo $item->link;
}
```

Produces;

- /example/
- /example/locations/items
- /example/locations/paris

I need to edit the `link` value IF the `name` key is `Items`. I essentially want to remove the last URL parameter so the output looks like this;

- /example/
- /example/locations
- /example/locations/paris

Note that it will not always be position `[1]` in the array, but the `name` value will always be `Items`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), passing it a function which checked for the `name` key being `Items` and if so returning the `dirname` of the `link` key:

```
array_walk($list, function (&$v) { if ($v->name == 'Items') $v->link = dirname($v->link); });
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Home
            [link] => /example/
        )    
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Items
            [link] => /example/locations
        )    
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Paris
            [link] => /example/locations/paris
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/48LWb)